# sed command or awk commands to remove text

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have this input file:

```
target_id          length   eff_length  est_counts  tpm
ENST00000583162.1   1066       967       1.69899    1.18376
ENST00000583355.1   891        792       13.8057    11.7445
ENST00000582528.5   5342       5243      21.3223    2.74003
ENST00000497744.1   964         865       0            0
ENST00000482564.1   1856       1757       3.29538    1.26367
ENST00000356654.8   4351        4252      56.2725    8.91668
ENST00000396684.2   4290        4191      0.206617   0.0332162
ENST00000541029.1   855         756       3.14783    2.80537
ENST00000537488.1   899         800       2.37306    1.99857
ENST00000264010.8   3939        3840      354.642    62.2241
ENST00000401394.5   2978        2879       28.362     6.63735
ENST00000566078.1   1627        1528        4.9964    2.2031
ENST00000595290.5   1242        1143         0            0
ENST00000595330.1   692          593          0           0
ENST00000596998.2   588          489          0            0
ENST00000374514.7   1810         1711       53.7113    21.1503
```

And I want to remove `.*` from the first column:

```
target_id          length   eff_length  est_counts  tpm
ENST00000583162.   1066       967       1.69899    1.18376
ENST00000583355.   891        792       13.8057    11.7445
ENST00000582528.   5342       5243      21.3223    2.74003
ENST00000497744.   964         865       0            0
ENST00000482564.   1856       1757       3.29538    1.26367
ENST00000356654.   4351        4252      56.2725    8.91668
ENST00000396684.   4290        4191      0.206617   0.0332162
ENST00000541029.   855         756       3.14783    2.80537
ENST00000537488.   899         800       2.37306    1.99857
ENST00000264010.   3939        3840      354.642    62.2241
ENST00000401394.   2978        2879       28.362     6.63735
ENST00000566078.   1627        1528        4.9964    2.2031
ENST00000595290.   1242        1143         0            0
ENST00000595330.   692          593          0           0
ENST00000596998.   588          489          0            0
ENST00000374514.   1810         1711       53.7113    21.1503
```

Please tell me what sed or awk command I can use to solve this issue.

Comment: Do you really want to leave the trailing `.`? That will make the transcript ID useless. While both `ENST00000448914.1` and `ENST00000448914` are valid, `ENST00000448914.` is not. Are you sure? Also, you might be interested in our sister site, [bioinformatics.se].

Answer (score 7):

The simplest approach would be to remove all numbers after the first `.` on every line:

```
$ sed 's/\.[0-9]*/\./' file
target_id          length   eff_length  est_counts  tpm
ENST00000583162.   1066       967       1.69899    1.18376
ENST00000583355.   891        792       13.8057    11.7445
ENST00000582528.   5342       5243      21.3223    2.74003
ENST00000497744.   964         865       0            0
ENST00000482564.   1856       1757       3.29538    1.26367
ENST00000356654.   4351        4252      56.2725    8.91668
ENST00000396684.   4290        4191      0.206617   0.0332162
ENST00000541029.   855         756       3.14783    2.80537
ENST00000537488.   899         800       2.37306    1.99857
ENST00000264010.   3939        3840      354.642    62.2241
ENST00000401394.   2978        2879       28.362     6.63735
ENST00000566078.   1627        1528        4.9964    2.2031
ENST00000595290.   1242        1143         0            0
ENST00000595330.   692          593          0           0
ENST00000596998.   588          489          0            0
ENST00000374514.   1810         1711       53.7113    21.1503
```

That will find the first `.` on the line and replace the `.` and any numbers after it with only the `.`. However, given that these are transcript IDs, you probably don't want the `.` either, so try this instead:

```
$ sed 's/\.[0-9]*//' file
target_id          length   eff_length  est_counts  tpm
ENST00000583162   1066       967       1.69899    1.18376
ENST00000583355   891        792       13.8057    11.7445
ENST00000582528   5342       5243      21.3223    2.74003
ENST00000497744   964         865       0            0
ENST00000482564   1856       1757       3.29538    1.26367
ENST00000356654   4351        4252      56.2725    8.91668
ENST00000396684   4290        4191      0.206617   0.0332162
ENST00000541029   855         756       3.14783    2.80537
ENST00000537488   899         800       2.37306    1.99857
ENST00000264010   3939        3840      354.642    62.2241
ENST00000401394   2978        2879       28.362     6.63735
ENST00000566078   1627        1528        4.9964    2.2031
ENST00000595290   1242        1143         0            0
ENST00000595330   692          593          0           0
ENST00000596998   588          489          0            0
ENST00000374514   1810         1711       53.7113    21.1503
```

If you could have a value in the first column that doesn't have a `.`, then these commands would change the next available column with a `.` followed by numbers. To limit to the first column explicitly, you could use one of these:

1. awk

   ```
   awk -v OFS='\t' '{sub(/\.[0-9]*/,"",$1)}1' file
   ```

   or, to leave the trailing `.`:

   ```
   awk -v OFS='\t' '{sub(/\.[0-9]*/,".",$1)}1' file
   ```
2. GNU sed

   ```
   sed -E 's/^(\S+)\.[0-9]*/\1/' file
   ```

   or, to leave the trailing `.`:

   ```
   sed -E 's/^(\S+)\.[0-9]*/\1./' file
   ```

   Most other sed implementations:

   ```
   sed -E 's/^([^[:blank:]]*)\.[0-9]*/\1/' file
   ```

   Any sed:

   ```
   sed 's/^\([^[:blank:]]*\)\.[0-9]*/\1/' file
   ```
3. Perl

   ```
   perl -pe 's/^(\S+)\.\d+/\1/' file
   ```

   or, to leave the trailing `.`:

   ```
   perl -pe 's/^(\S+)\.\d+/\1./' file
   ```

Comment: sed 's/\.[0-9]*//' file  I used this but it delete other column also.

Comment: @aman that doesn't make sense. Is your input file exactly as you showed in the question? What operating system are you using?

Comment: the file is same just the no. are less i given to you .I will give u whole file.

Comment: I will send it please check it ,thanks

Comment: @aman please don't post answers unless you actually want to answer your own question. Just edit your original question instead. Also, please answer the questions I asked: 1) what operating system are you using and 2) do you really want to leave the `.` as you originally said, or do you also want to remove the `.`?

Comment: Anyway, both commands I gave will only affect the 1st column, none of the others. The only way another column can be changed is if the 1st column doesn't have a `.`. If that is the issue, @aman, try the updated commands.

Comment: @EdMorton good suggestions all, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

command

```
awk '{gsub(/\.*/,"",$1);print $0}' file.txt
```

output

```
target_id length eff_length est_counts tpm
ENST000005831621 1066 967 1.69899 1.18376
ENST000005833551 891 792 13.8057 11.7445
ENST000005825285 5342 5243 21.3223 2.74003
ENST000004977441 964 865 0 0
ENST000004825641 1856 1757 3.29538 1.26367
ENST000003566548 4351 4252 56.2725 8.91668
ENST000003966842 4290 4191 0.206617 0.0332162
ENST000005410291 855 756 3.14783 2.80537
ENST000005374881 899 800 2.37306 1.99857
ENST000002640108 3939 3840 354.642 62.2241
ENST000004013945 2978 2879 28.362 6.63735
ENST000005660781 1627 1528 4.9964 2.2031
ENST000005952905 1242 1143 0 0
ENST000005953301 692 593 0 0
ENST000005969982 588 489 0 0
ENST000003745147 1810 1711 53.7113 21.1503
```